# Minor design issue with flag summary page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

There's something slightly wrong with the header on the flag summary page (on your [profile page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/current), click the "*x* helpful flags" link); the dotted line coincides with some of the descenders (e.g. the *g* of the word *Flags*):

[image]

It looks much better with a little more spacing, e.g. on Mathematics Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow:

[image]

[image]

I've checked the CSS rules and when disabling the specific padding rule for the `subheader` div, it looks much better:

[image]

Another page which suffers the same fate is the [404 page in the /users/ section](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed with the [roll-out of the new design across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/295232):

[image]